# The method setDefaultPushCallback in the type PushService is not applicable

Tags: android

error :    `The method setDefaultPushCallback(Context, Class<? extends Activity>) in the type PushService is not applicable for the arguments (new Runnable(){}, Class<MenuActivity>)`

following [parse push notifications tutorial](https://www.parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)

above error showing

```
try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GetOtherData getOtherData = new GetOtherData();
                getOtherData.execute();
                PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MenuActivity.class);
                ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
                ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getApplicationContext()` or `yourActivity.this` to get context..
Like this...

```
try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                GetOtherData getOtherData = new GetOtherData();
                getOtherData.execute();
                PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(YourActivity.this, MenuActivity.class);
                ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
                ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: No error is not showing but app is not starting with modified code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In setDefaultPushCallback you should specify the activity to be shown if the user presses back button. I could compile by changing this line:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MenuActivity.class)
```

For this one:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version number of android `parse-xxx.jar`(xxx is the version number), if you use the old version, The method `setDefaultPushCallback` would be not applicable, I've met this error when use the parse1.4.4.jar